# LDD not rendering

Tags: ldd

I've dug out the LDD application I found on an older hard drive.
It seems however, that it has problems rendering the bricks and models:

[image]

I am running LDD 4.3.8 on Windows7 Ultimate (64Bit) with Administrative Priviledges. I have DirectX 11 installed and I am using the newest NVidia drivers. I am also pretty sure, that LDD has run previously on this machine (though I am not quite sure, which version it was at that point of time....)

Does someone know, how to fix this problem?

---

*Edit: I think the problem lies in my 'db.lif' file. It would be nice, if someone has a working database file for me to download...*

Comment: why not download a new complete installer from http://ldd.lego.com/ ??

Comment: Almost certainly the application needs some share resource that is no longer present. This is something the installer probably does.

Comment: If you try and place one of the bricks from the sidebar into the scene is rendered at all?

Comment: @ chicks: I have redownloaded a new installer from ldd.lego.com - but it did not change anything :/

@Ambo100: No - the scene will not be rendered at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem: My "AppData/Roaming/LEGO Company"-folder somehow seemed to be a symbolic link to a non-existent folder. It did not help reinstalling the application, but I fixed the link issue -- which in the end fixed the whole not-rendering-problem.

However, thank you very much for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you uninstall the current LDD software completely. You can download a 30 day trial of [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_uninstall_features.html) to remove LDD using the 'Forced Uninstall' feature. It's good for removing partially installed software, but it isn't necessary, you can use the Uninstaller built into your operating system to do a standard uninstallation.

Download the most recent version of [LDD from the LEGO website](http://ldd.lego.com/en-gb/).